# Displaying a jquery dialog with text inside (absolute middle)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to create a little jQuery dialog with only one image + text inside. I would like this to be absolute middle (vertically + horizontally).

Here is what I do:

**Html:**

```
<div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none; text-align:center; margin-top: 10px;">
    <h3>
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/pictures/busy.gif")" alt="Wait..." style="margin-right: 10px;" />
        Please wait...
    </h3>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    height: 80,
    modal: true
});
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

Here is the result: for the first time the dialog is showed:

[image]

Next time the dialog is showed:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is not the good way of doing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a loading message you should consider using a simple div, positioned absolutely in the middle of the screen, which you could control better.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal but the advantage of using a jQuery dialog is the modal property which block the user until the page is loaded (ajax)

Comment: then use 2 div, one as an overlay which will block the page and the other as the message.